# Unable to Import CSV data in Google Apps Script. What is wrong?

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to simply import a CSV file into a specific Google spreadsheet and specific sheet. I've seen multiple versions people have used to include CSVs into Google Sheets, but I can't seen to get any to work. What am I doing wrong? In this example I get the error "Could not parse text".
[Link to CSV file in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/164cN51eKfxTnn24W8tfqxaNc_uQUJl2u/view?usp=sharing)

```
function importConduitRunsSchdeule() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("CONDUIT_RUNS_REVIT.csv")
  var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  if(csvData.length > 0) {
    ss.getSheetByName('CONDUIT_RUNS_REVIT')
      .getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  } else
    throw 'Blank file';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your provided CSV data, it seems that the delimiter is `\t`. And, between the column "C" and "D" has no delimiter like `"4"""`. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString();
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
```

#### To:

```
var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString().replace(/"""/g, '"\t""');
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv, "\t");
```

- In this case, the column "D" is the empty column. If you want to remove this empty column, please modify it as follows.

  - To:

    ```
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString().replace(/"""/g, '"');
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv, "\t");
    ```

#### Reference:

- [parseCsv(csv, delimiter)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter)

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. For my own knowledge, could you explain this part (/"""/g, '"\t""') ?

Comment: @Shane Wall Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `(/"""/g, '"\t""')`. In this case, in your CSV data, `"4"""` of the part of columns "C" and "D" is converted to `"4"\t""` by inserting the delimiter of `\t`. By this, the columns "C" and "D" can be correctly parsed. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.